# CakePHP and Pages Controller trouble

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm very new to CakePHP, for my first project I'm making a mostly static site with some forms etc. I use CakePHP 2.2

As I read in CookBook for static pages I should use default Pages Controller " If you make the view file app/View/Pages/about_us.ctp you can access it using the url http://example.com/pages/about_us. bla bla bla"
So I've made new view in /View/Pages/ and then filled it with some lorem ipsum.

When I try to access it with http://example.com/pages/myview I get a Missing Method in PagesController error.

So I've tried to delete all stuff in app/Controller/PagesController.php and fill it with some basic things like

```
class PagesController extends AppController {
public function index() {
        }
public function staticpagename() {
        }
}
```

and now it works, I have access to my pages with two different views.
But I want to add about 6 or 7 static pages which requires different views.
Writing tons of  public function *staticpagename* looks kind of wrong way. What should I do to correctly achieve my goals: static pages without flooding controller with empty methods?

Comment: I prefer create one controller to each static pages, but, ok, follow docs.

Comment: You need to restore all codes, and route static pages to `display` method

Comment: @GabrielSantos thank you I've restored  
Router::connect('/pages/*', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display')); and now everything works.

Comment: You are welcome. Posted as answer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to restore all codes of `PagesController`, and route static pages to `display` method.